# Change the notification icon/badge/title color on Android when using Javascript Web Push PWA

Tags: android, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, web-push, manifest.json

How do you change the icon (or I think its called badge) and title color of a notification when using web push?

I have both normal push notifications working from my website, and push notifications from a PWA

I have the following:

```
const title = data.notification.title || "Something";
   const options = {
    body: data.notification.body,
    icon: '/images/icons/webpush_icon.png',
    //iconColor: '#43BDFF',  // Can something like this be added?
    badge: '/images/icons/webpush_icon2.png'
  };

  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
```

When this fires, the notification comes through just fine, and the icon is showing (it is a white shape with a transparent background, so this changes to grey on the notification bar as expected). However, the icon is along with the title is showing as white/grey on the drop-down notification list. Other Apps show the icon and title in a single color.

So, can the color of the notification icon/title be set when sending push notifications from a website? If not, what about from a PWA (this installs using js and a manifest.json)

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "short_name": "Name",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/PWA_icon_192_any_outline.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/PWA_icon_512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/PWA_icon_192_mask_outline.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/PWA_icon_192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
            
  "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
  "theme_color": "#43BDFF",
  
  
  

  "description": "Description",
  "orientation": "portrait-primary",
  "gcm_sender_id": "1234********"
 
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found out how to make it finally? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In Android it is called [Accent color](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons#small-icon-accent-color) and can unfortunately not be set in the notifications today (March 2023).